# Can I send a HTTP redirect to a url with an anchor?

Tags: http, http-status-code-302

Is it possible to send a response with 302 status code to a url like this:

http://mysite.com/something/#somethingelse

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: Web Server? If you're doing this using mod_rewrite you it won't work as #'s are escaped

Comment: @Manni yes I did try that, but had a error in my code, that's why it didn't work. Now it works.
@Shiraz I'm using python.

Comment: Does that mean that your question is no longer relevant?

Comment: @Manni are you having a bad day?

Comment: No, I'm fine, thanks. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the fragment identifier. This was a known bug in the HTTP spec, fixed in subsequent revisions of the spec. See RFC 9110.

Answer (score 4):

Following the HTTP specification, the value for the [`Location` header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) must be an *absoluteURI* value. And that is according to the [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) (they just changed the name from *absoluteURI* to *absolute-URI*):

```
absolute-URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]
```

So theoretically the fragment is not allowed as part of the value. But the browsers can handle it.

Answer (score 4):

With strict reading [RFC2616](http://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#header.location) does not allow fragments in Location header values, since they are not part of absolute URIs. However, with the [IETF's HTTP rewrite draft](http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/) [this was fixed](http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/6).

Recently [Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke) put up a comparison how browsers handle URI fragments (that's what the HTML anchor tags deal with) in the Location header: http://www.greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/redirects.html

So the answer ist: Yes, you can put fragments in Location header URIs.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be no problem in doing so from PHP:

```
Header(
    "Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Status_codes",
    true,
    302
);
```

Comment: I know this guy!

Comment: I want to do this but if I do this there is a problem. If I go on my link I will redirect to in this case ````http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Status_codes/```` and the / at the end shows not the anchor point. I coud rename the anchor point to ````Status_codes/````  I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's the browser which doesn't send the hash to the server, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

While the original [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) allowed only `absoluteURI` in the `Location` header, as the other (older) answers explain, the current [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) allows any `URI-reference`, either a full URI (with fragment possibly included), or even a relative URI, resolved against the current effective URI. And it even explicitly describes the behavior of fragments during redirection (if the `Location` header includes the fragment, it is used, if not, the original fragment is inherited and applied after the redirection).

I.e. **yes, you can**, it is even officially standardized now.